# Can I use a build parameter to populate another build parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have defined, for my deploy job, two parameters:

- JOB_NAME
- BUILD_NUMBER

The job name is a simple CHOICE parameter, set to

```
JOB1
JOB2
```

I then have the BUILD_NUMBER, I made as extensible choice with the following Groovy script used to populate the choice:

```
def builds = []

def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("what do I put here?")

job.builds.each {
it -> 
if(it.result == hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS){
   builds.add(it.number);
}
}
return builds
```

My problem is, as the above code states, how can I get the *current* JOB_NAME value so that I can correctly display its builds so far? I also need that, whatever the user changes the JOB_NAME choice to, the BUILD_NUMBER choice also updates by running the script again to get the build numbers.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Comment: I didn't get the requirement much, but I believe you are using env variables which jenkins supports, ${env.JOB_NAME}, for more info you can refer here : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Comment: It does not seem to work...am I supposed to see that variable in my groovy job? Also I would need a listener to make the second choice change when the first one does :(